# Debug windows service permissions

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, service

I have a program that uses `OpenService(SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS)` to open a service, but it results in error code 5, `Access Denied`.

However in `services.msc` I can edit its attributes such as `service account name` or fail controls.

1. I'm not sure what's wrong. How should I debug this problem?
2. Where can I view the service permissions and who can open this service? I have Administrator privilege.

Comment: look `QueryServiceObjectSecurity`